# Unable to make my OS X app (written in swift) launch at login

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, osx-yosemite

Some details:

- I am not enrolled into Mac Developer program, hence the code is not signed.
- I am not sandboxing the app.
- It's a status bar only app, no dock or menu will appear.

Here's what I did:

1. Added a new project for helper app on top my existing main app project.
2. In main app settings:

   - Added `ServiceManagement.framework` framework to my main app.
   - Set `Strip Debug Symbols During Copy` to `NO`
   - In `Build Phases` tab, under `Copy Files`, added `Contents/Library/LoginItems` as `Subpath`. And added my Helper App.app
3. For helper app settings:

   - Set `Application is background only` to `YES`
   - Under `Build Settings`, set `Skip Install` to `YES`

`Hocus Pocus.app` is my main app and `Hocus Pocus Helper.app` is helper app.

In `AppDelegate` of helper app, my code is:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {        
    NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().launchApplication("Hocus Pocus.app")
    NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate(self)
}
```

In `AppDelegate` of main app:

```
...
override init() {
    self.mainBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    let path = mainBundle.bundlePath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(
        "Contents/Library/LoginItems/Hocus Pocus Helper.app")
    self.helperBundle = NSBundle(path: path)!

    super.init()
}
...
...
func makeThisAppStartAtLogin(state: Int) {
    let result = SMLoginItemSetEnabled(helperBundle.bundleIdentifier!, Boolean(state))        
    if result != 0 {
        println("success")
    }
    else {
        println("failed")
    }
}
```

It's not working when I call `makeThisAppStartAtLogin(1)`, why?

---

1. Apple documentation mentions:

   > The Boolean enabled state of the helper application. This value is effective only for the currently logged in user. If true, the helper application will be started immediately (and upon subsequent logins) and kept running. If false, the helper application will no longer be kept running.

   When I call `makeThisAppStartAtLogin(_:)`, it should start helper app immediately. But it doesn't seem to be doing that.
2. The `if` block prints `success`.
3. In Helper App code, I also sent the path to `launchApplication(_:)` instead of app name, it did not make any difference.
4. I have ran this app from default debug directory and also under `/Applications`
5. I have also tried following, it didn't make any difference:

   ```
   ...
   let launchDaemon: CFStringRef = "avi.Hocus-Pocus-Helper"
   if SMLoginItemSetEnabled(launchDaemon, Boolean(state)) {
   ...
   ```
6. I have checked that helper app is copied to main app at correct path.
7. When I launch the helper app manually, either from debug folder or from main app's Contents, it does launches main app and kill itself, as it should.
8. [Here's](https://github.com/avinassh/Hocus-Pocus/tree/loginitems) the full repository, if you are interested. Check `loginitems` branch.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: Yes, I did. But had to use different method. I will post the code

Comment: Hi, could post an example of what you did? I tried this method and didn't work for me either :/